# How to bless boot partition for Ubuntu 22.04 on an Intel (2009) MacBookPro

Tags: macos, startup, unix, firmware, bless

I asked this on the [Ubuntu exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462566/how-to-bless-boot-partition-for-ubuntu-22-04-on-macbookpro) where I personally think it belongs, but they directed me here so please don't close this and tell me to ask there.

I'm booting from the Mac OS X Lion installation disk that comes with the laptop and then opening a terminal from inside that.

So after trying out different variations, here are the results:

`bless --device /dev/disk0s1 --setBoot`
doesn't appear to do anything. Still long timeout on white screen. System still booting afterwards.

`bless --device /dev/disk0s2 --setBoot` same as above.

`bless --device /dev/disk0s1 --setBoot --legacy` still long timeout on white screen. After that system goes to black screen and won't boot into Ubuntu.

There are only `/dev/disk0s1` and `/dev/disk0s2` listed in fdisk for `/dev/disk0`. I'm assuming `/dev/disk0s1` is `/boot/efi` but I have no idea.

I have performed a full-disk install of Ubuntu 22.04 on an old MacBook Pro (MBP 5.2 from 2009, Core 2 Duo) machine completely wiping OSX in the process.

I'm now facing the known issue of the 30-second white screen delay on boot. I already figured out I have to use the `bless` utility to set Ubuntu as the boot partition. My question is what command-line arguments do I have to pass exactly? All examples on the internet make use of the `--legacy` option and talk about BIOS mode but from what I could figure out my Ubuntu installation is using EFI ([the /sys/firmware/efi directory exists](https://askubuntu.com/a/162896/1484565)).

I assume then that I shouldn't use the `--legacy` option when blessing the partition.

Here's the output of `df -h` when run in Ubuntu:

```
t30@macbook:~$ df -h
tmpfs           770M    1,7M  768M    1% /run
/dev/sda2       457G     12G  423G    3% /
tmpfs           3,8G       0  3,8G    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       511M    6,1M  505M    2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           770M     52K  770M    1% /run/user/1000
```

I think I should invoke bless like this (replacing /dev/sda1 with whatever it's mounted as under bless).

```
bless --device /dev/sda1 --setBoot
```

Is there a guide or can someone confirm which partition do I have to bless?

Comment: Ubuntu should appear in the Mac Startup Manager. I am not sure if you can select a default by holding down the control key. Your Mac might be to old for that ability. Did you install using a flash drive or DVD?

Comment: I have a 2011 iMac with High Sierra, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and Windows 11 installed. When booted to macOS Recovery, I needed to enter the following commands to bless Ubuntu: `diskutil mount disk0s1; bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI --setBoot` Note that the EFI partition (`disk0s1`) was created by macOS and therefore was given the default label of `EFI`. Your label may be different. Also, an alternative to `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` might be `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I think all Mac OS X partitions were completely wiped and replaced by Ubuntu. I have only two partitions for /dev/disk0. /dev/disk0s1 which shows up as type "EFI" and /dev/disk0s2 which shows up as "Linux files" in the system information utility of the Mac OS X Install disk.

Comment: I was just pointing out that entering `diskutil mount disk0s1` may result in `/dev/disk0s1` getting mounted somewhere other than on `/Volumes/EFI`. If necessary make the appropriate substitution in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you - Excellent edits to the main post - thanks everyone

Comment: @DavidAnderson entering `diskutil mount disk0s1` returns the following error `Volume on disk0s1 failed to mount`. Same for disk0s2.

Comment: Using a Snow Leopard DVD, I was able to install Snow Leopard in a virtual machine. Next, I booted the virtual machine from the DVD and tried the command `diskutil mount disk0s1`. You are correct, the command does not work. What did work was the commands `mkdir -p /Volumes/EFI; mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/EFI`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson That worked. I then tried your sggested command `bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI --setBoot` but unfortunately it had no noticeable effect. The directory was mounted though and I also verified that the `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` file actually existed under that path.

Comment: I tried `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` as well but it also had no effect. I still have a white screen for about 35 to 40 seconds on boot. Are there perhaps any other unrelated reasons that can cause this?

Comment: The `Boot ROM Version` of the MBP is `MBP52.008E.B05` and the `SMC Version (system)` is `1.42f4` if that makes any difference.

Comment: I suppose some of your problems may be caused the fact the OS X DVD you have is not the one that came with your Mac. You have a 2009 Mac and Lion wasn't released until 2011.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu to EFI boot on my 2011 iMac. I can boot Ubuntu by holding down the option key at startup, then selecting the icon labeled `EFI Boot`. This not only boots Ubuntu but also makes Ubuntu the default to boot on startup. In other words, I do not need to enter the `bless` command to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you may be right. From what I understand `bless` manipulates the variables `efi-boot-device` and `efi-boot-device-data` in NVRAM. After invoking `bless` I can see that the contents of them have changed when examining NVRAM with `/usr/sbin/nvram -xp`. However after a reboot, the changes are no longer there and the variables contain their previous values again.

Comment: I had a similar problem with the `SystemAudioVolume` variable that after a reboot would always contain its old value again, even though  I had changed it to something else with `/usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00`. I will try it with a Leopard disk then, maybe that will make a difference?

Comment: OK I guess I made some progress. Mounting the disk0s1 partition and then issuing `bless --folder /Volumes/EFI --file /Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi --setBoot` is at least doing something. The white screen is now "only" about 20 seconds as opposed to 40 seconds previously, however after that I'm now in Grub's bootloader menu screen with another 20 second Grub timeout counting down instead of just booting Ubuntu. To be honest I'm close to giving up on this, I don't know how much time I have already wasted on this...

Comment: According to [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2009.html), MacBookPro5,2 models where shipped with with OS X Leopard 10.5.6 or 10.5.7. If your Leopard is earlier, then you might be better off using Snow Leopard. You can change the GRUB timeout by editing `/etc/default/grub`. I am using `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`, which is 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for all your help but I think it's impossible. I believe whatever I do with `bless` is kept being reset after a reboot. Must be the MacBook's firmware doing it or something. I can `bless` `disk0s1`, `BOOTX64.EFI`, `grubx64.efi` or whatever I want and directly after doing that, a `bless --info --getBoot` will return `disk0s1`, but invoking the same command after a reboot will then return `Boot option does not match XML representation. XML representation doesn't match true boot preference`. I tried it with `Lion`, `Snow Leopard` and `Leopard` installer disks.

Comment: I now even tried copying `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` into `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` because they were not the same files and then blessed that with `bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI --setBoot`, but it doesn't make any difference. I think the original `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` was the same file as `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`, at least they had the exact same file size. I have no idea what else to try anymore.

Comment: Running the command `efibootmgr` in a ubuntu terminal prints out
`BootCurrent: 0080`
`BootOrder: 0080, 0000`
`Boot0000* ubuntu`
`Boot0080* Mac OS X`
`BootFFFF*`
I don't know if that's what it's supposed to say.